# Write a simple c code in loadrunner

Tags: c, loadrunner

I received string `"ZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6&#xd;&#xa;cHJvd&#x2b;jwvc2FtbHA6UmVzcG9uc2U&#x2b;"` from server response which I wish to convert into `"ZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6&%0D%0AcHJvd%2Bjwvc2FtbHA6UmVzcG9uc2U%2B"` format.
I find it difficult to do hence seeking help.

BR,
AK

Comment: put some more details in your question. Show some part of code and explain scenario.

Comment: Flagging this as "Too broad"

Comment: So basically you want to convert sequences of _&#xNN;_ to _%NN_ (or in particular: _&#xN;_ to _%0N_) - where _N_ is a placeholder for a _HEX_ digit -  most likely they represent non printable chars. Right?

Comment: The scenario is, I'm doing correlation for SAML response in loadrunner & received response is in "ZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6**&#xd;****&#xa;**cHJvd**&#x2b;**jwvc2FtbHA6UmVzcG9uc2U&**#x2b;**" format. Now when I checked for next request which is using & sending this string in "ZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6&**%0D****%0A**cHJvd**%2B**jwvc2FtbHA6UmVzcG9uc2U**%2B**" format to the server.
If I'm able to do the conversion in required format & pass it to server then an then only server will process it & transaction will pass.

Note:"&#xd;", "&#xa;", "&#x2b;" is fixed pattern in the string.

BR,
AK

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using an inbuilt function in Loadrunner itself.

Here is the code I used:

```
lr_save_string("ZXM6dGM6U0FNTDoyLjA6&#xd;&#xa;cHJvd&#x2b;jwvc2FtbHA6UmVzcG9uc2U&#x2b;", "HTML_text");
web_convert_param("HTML_text", "SourceEncoding=HTML",  "TargetEncoding=URL", LAST );
lr_output_message("converted result: %s", lr_eval_string("{HTML_text}"));
```